# How to Remove a Metadata Schema from a Folder using Core Services?

Tags: 2011, core-service

I want to remove the Metadata Schema from a folder using the core service API. I have tried setting the `MetaDataSchema` and `MetaData` properties of the folder to `null` but this doesn't change anything.

```
var organizationalItem = (FolderData)client.Read(organizationalItemID, new ReadOptions());
organizationalItem.Metadata = null;
organizationalItem.MetadataSchema = null;
organizationalItem = (FolderData)client.Save(organizationalItem, new ReadOptions());
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you ensure that this does not changed anything?
Did you check the value of `organizationalItem` variable at debug mode or you have checked the folder property in CME? If it is later case, check after clearing your cache and restarting the COM+

Comment: @PankajGaur I figured it out, hopefully this will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like I have to set the `MetaDataSchema` to an "empty" `LinkToSchemaData` object instead of `null`

```
var organizationalItem = (FolderData)client.Read(organizationalItemID, new ReadOptions());
var emptySchema = new LinkToSchemaData();
emptySchema.IdRef = "tcm:0-0-0";
organizationalItem.MetadataSchema = emptySchema;
organizationalItem = (FolderData)client.Save(organizationalItem, new ReadOptions());
```